# Android SQLite: Replace old database with a new one or use migration scripts

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an Android app that uses a SQLite database and [Active Android](http://www.activeandroid.com) as ORM. On each app update I need to ship my database with new/updated data. This is what i've been doing

1. I have a **my_app.db** database
2. I make modifications on the rows, tables, etc. of the **my_app.db**
3. I save the modified **my_app.db** as **my_app_v2.db** ( and so on )
4. I replace the **my_app.db** file of the assets folder with the **my_app_v2.db** and set it as the default database
5. I compile and run the program using the newly created **my_app_v2.db**

So when the user gets the app, it will be using the **my_app_v2.db** with new contents.

I know that Active Android [supports migration scripts](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Schema-migrations), but on each database update I need to add/update about 2000+ records. So for each database update I would need a migration script with 2000+ insert/update statements, it means that for 3+ consecutive upgrades the app would have to execute about 6000+ statements.

I want to know if my approach of replace the whole database with a new one is a bad practice and the migrations scripts should be prefered.

Comment: for insert /update query you are passing separate query or using transactions for querying ??

Comment: As I said, I'm shipping the app with a new database with all update contents, therefore I'm not using insert / update query to update the database in the onUpdate() method.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793004/android-sqlite-database-why-drop-table-and-recreate-on-upgrade

Comment: Do you change the data only or also the structure?

Comment: @YoannHercouet Only the data. I rarely change the structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to do that (renaming stuff or anything)

You just need to change your database version and write a sql command to alter your previous table to migrate from version A to B.

Look at this link:

[Android: upgrading DB version and adding new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133597/android-upgrading-db-version-and-adding-new-table)

Comment: My "problem" is that I want to migrate the database with new/updated rows and not just create / alter a table. Also, if I replace the old database ( outdated content and Version 1) from assets folder with another database ( same name as the old one, new/updated contents and Version 2 ) it would work?

Comment: You can alter your db colmuns or even rows. Just write an update sql command. Whatever it is. You need to delete all old rows ? Do it there. You need to keeep old ones and add some other rows ? Simply just write the sql command to do this. Whatever you can do with sql command you can do in your update session ;)

Comment: As i read your question you have put your db on asset folder which you dont need to do this and its a wrong practice becuase then onUpgrade wont work for you. Then you need to handle the DB upgrade by yourself. You must do it manually before you open the connection to db.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you could apply this way on your app but here is what I am doing to retrieve new data from another database.

For my apps I use a sync system that will daily check if a new database is available on GoogleDrive (in case the user is using different devices).

When a new database backup is available (meaning I have to retrieve data for this device), I get back the database backup and attach it to the existing one by using:

```
attach database database/path as new_db
```

Then I just execute this command for every table in order to update the existing database with the records from the one I retrieved:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table SELECT * FROM retrieved_database.table
```

Of course it will replace all existing data, but this way I also handle the records that have been modified. This method avoids the full replacement of the existing database, I just run an integrity check at the end to be sure all is ok.

This method is ok for me since I have a few tables and the data is light, it might be a bad idea for heavy databases.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, i used like this

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;
private Context mContext;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "xxxx";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME_OLD = "xxxx_old";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 12;
private String pathToSaveDBFile, absolutepathToSaveDBFile;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;



public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context mContext) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    }
    return sInstance;
}

/**
 * initialization constructor
 *
 * @param context
 */

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
    pathToSaveDBFile = new StringBuffer(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()).append("/").append(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
    absolutepathToSaveDBFile = new StringBuffer(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()).append("/").append(DATABASE_NAME_OLD).toString();

}

/**
 * prepare database related process
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void prepareDatabase() throws IOException {
    //boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (checkDataBase()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Database exists.");
  //            int currentDBVersion = getVersionId();
        if (DATABASE_VERSION > getVersionId()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Database version is higher than old.");
                  if (renameDatabase()) {
                      Log.d(TAG, "renameDatabase() ");

                       try {
                           if (copyDataBase()) {


                                     deleteDb();
                                      setVersionId(DATABASE_VERSION);
                                 }




                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }


        }
    } else {
        try {
            /// copy db
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


/**
 * db exist or not?
 *
 * @return db checked status
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    Log.d(TAG, "checkDataBase()");
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try {
        File file = new File(pathToSaveDBFile);
        checkDB = file.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "checkDataBase: " + checkDB);
    return checkDB;
}

/**
 * db copying
 *
 * @return db copy status
 */
private Boolean copyDataBase() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "copyDataBase()");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pathToSaveDBFile);
        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open("db/" + DATABASE_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        is.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * db renaming
 *
 * @return boolean status
 */
private boolean renameDatabase() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "renameDatabase: ");
        File from = new File(pathToSaveDBFile);
        File to = new File(absolutepathToSaveDBFile);
        if (from.renameTo(to)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 *
 *
 * @return boolen status
 */
private boolean revertBack_to_OlderName() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "renameDatabase: ");
        File from = new File(absolutepathToSaveDBFile);
        File to = new File(pathToSaveDBFile);
        if (from.renameTo(to)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * db deletion
 *
 * delete db
 */
public void deleteDb() {
    File file = new File(absolutepathToSaveDBFile);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        Log.d(TAG, "Database deleted.");
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    db.close();
    super.close();
}



/**
 * get db version info
 *
 * @return version no
 */
private int getVersionId() {
    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToSaveDBFile, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        String query = "SELECT " + AS_DB_VERSION_NUMBER + " FROM " + AS_DB_VERSION_TABLE;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int v = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        close();
        return v;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return 0;
    }


}

/**
 * set db version no to
 * @param version
 *
 * @return status
 */
private boolean setVersionId(int version) {
    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToSaveDBFile, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(AS_DB_VERSION_NUMBER, version);
        db.update(AS_DB_VERSION_NUMBER, values, AS_DB_VERSION_ID + " = 1", null);
        close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

you can use these code in your contest